# Viabilidade da $_SESSION PHP

Tags: php

Pesquisei em alguns lugares mas não encontrei uma resposta definitiva, guardar dados como: cnpj, numero de celular, nome, etc... na variável $_SESSION do PHP é uma boa opção? Pois sinto que estou fazendo muitas requisições para o banco de dados e se for seguro e uma boa opção usar a $_SESSION eu não precisaria acessar o banco tantas vezes. Exemplo, ao invés de fazer isso em mais de uma página:

```
$usuario = new Usuario();
$dados_usuario = $usuario->getTodosDados();
```

Mudar para:

```
$_SESSION['dados_usuario'] = $usuario->getTodosDados();
```

Ai não precisaria ficar acessando o banco de dados mais de uma vez. Seria viável?

Comment: Pode ser viável sim, pois, por padrão, a sessão ficará salva em arquivo no seu servidor; e o custo de ler um arquivo local pode ser menor que a comunicação com o banco de dados - principalmente se este for remoto. Ainda você pode configurar a sessão e otimizar o processo, por exemplo, salvando em Redis ao invés de arquivo. Faça o teste e conclua por conta própria.